# Spark Reading Json

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I try to make the examples on http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#sql

I tried this command on shell :

```
val df = sqlContext.read.json("examples/src/main/resources/people.json")
```

It gives an error : "no input paths specified in job"

Why this problem happens ? How can I deal with it ?

Thanks.

Comment: Hmm I dont know.I am new to spark and I dont understand about the warnings

Comment: All those examples on that page assume you started spark-shell from the directory that you extracted Spark to, so if the path that you specified to the JSON file is not there, then you get "no input paths specified"

Answer (score 2):

The error means that you didn't start your spark-shell in the right folder since the path is a relative path. To solve the problem, you either need to change your working directory to the spark home directory or change the path to an absolute path.

Let's say if your spark is installed in a folder called `/Applications/spark-1.6.1` for mac, then you can either first navigate to that folder in your shell then run `spark-shell` or run:

```
scala> val df = sqlContext.read.json("/Applications/spark-1.6.1/examples/src/main/resources/people.json")

scala> df.show()
+----+-------+
| age|   name|
+----+-------+
|null|Michael|
|  30|   Andy|
|  19| Justin|
+----+-------+
```